# Define a Blazor Page using .razor.cs file only; no .razor file

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I was hoping the "Test.razor.cs" file below (with no corresponding "Test.razor" file hence no "partial" ) would actually work as a Page for example. But I get the "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." error when going to ".../Test"

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using NorthWind.UI.Shared;

namespace NorthWind.UI.Pages
{
    public class Test : ComponentBase
    {

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SurveyPrompt));
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Title", $"Some Test");
            builder.CloseComponent();

            base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add it to the pages that Blazor can evaluate too (other than adding a front end .razor file )?

Comment: Also added Issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31162

Comment: I would ask why you would want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: While you've called your file Test.razor.cs, it's really just Test.cs - there's no razor involved.  As @enet says below declare a bare bones route (page) with the component and [at]page directive in it.  Remember the [at]page attribute must be unique on an SPA.  Classes aren't, you can instantiate them many times in a project or in the same component, so there's a reason why you can't declared them with an [at]page directive.  Many of us who have worked with Blazor for a while stop using the work page - it can be very misleading.

Comment: @BrettJB I am generating pages using code generation tools, then overriding the partials to customize (https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars that doesn't support file extensions other than .cs or .ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute` to the class

```
    [Route("/Test")]
    public partial class Test : ComponentBase
    {

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SurveyPrompt));
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Title", $"Some Test");
            builder.CloseComponent();

            base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        }
    }
```